# Why is iTunes 64 bit running as 32 bit application under Windows?

Tags: itunes, windows, 64-bit

I've downloaded the 64 bit Version of iTunes and I'm wondering why it's running as a 32 bit application under Windows 7 (of course 64 bit)?

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The 64-bit version of iTunes you downloaded contains 64-bit drivers for Windows 7, however the application itself is still a 32-bit application.  You should see your iTunes installed in (default) C:\Program Files (x86)\ and the iPod helper files installed in C:\Program Files.