# How can I tell if I have the 64-bit version of iTunes installed?

Tags: itunes, windows

As I understand it, [the 64-bit version of iTunes is actually a 32-bit application](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/19975/22563), and so appears in the `Program Files (x86)` folder. Is there a way to see if the version of iTunes I've installed is the 32-bit version or the 64-bit version?

Comment: AFAIK, you cannot install a x64 version on a W7 32bit version. So you could check that. Since you don't provide any details about Windows or the iTunes version it's very hard to give more answer.

Comment: @Robuust The answer should be applicable to the current iTunes version (11), and all versions of Windows that support it. Also, attempting to install iTunes gives no indication about the version currently installed.

Comment: Where are the iPod helper files located at?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In answer to whether a 64-bit installation shows up, listed as 32-bit in the Task Manager, per https://discussions.apple.com/message/18034729#18034729:

That's normal on a 64-bit version of iTunes. (It's a mix of 32-bit and 64-bit componentry, and the itunes.exe is 32-bit.)

Is your iPodservice.exe running as 64-bit? If so, and your itunes version is 9.x or higher, you've got a 64-bit iTunes installed.

Answer (score 1):

On OS X, you can open iTunes and go to iTunes -> About iTunes and it will tell you. On Windows, you can get to the same dialogue by going to ? -> Info, it won't tell you though. You can open the task manager and if there is a *32 behind the process name, it is 32 bit.

It looks like the Installer is 64 bit but the application remains 32 bit on Windows.

Comment: As stated in the OP, the application is always a 32-bit process, even if the 64-bit version is installed, so looking in the Task Manager won't answer the question.